# Возможно ли написать с новой строки?

Tags: c#

Использую анимацию загрузки во время авторизации

```
Animations animations = new Animations();
      string loadingTest = "Authorize....";
      Console.Write(loadingTest);
      Console.CursorVisible = false;
      do
      {
        animations.LoadingBar(loadingTest, 0, 0);
        animations.Ready();
      }
      while (!Program.Vk.UserId.HasValue);
```

Но если авторизация выполнилась до того,как анимация проигралась не до конца то 1 смс будит в той же строке, что и анимация.Возможно ли принудительно писать с новой строки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` либо добавить в выводимый текст `\n`...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну так я и пишу через Console.WriteLine - дело в том, что если анимация *** не закончилась, то 1-вое сообщение выводиться в строке с анимацией

Comment: `...ну так я и пишу через Console.WriteLine...` а где это видно? Вы же привели пример кода, который выводит анимацию, а вывод строки с SMS нет.

Comment: Ну так перед выводом останавливайте анимацию, в чём проблема?